# Why does setText() cause TextView to be re-printed at the top of the screen?

Tags: android, android-layout

[edit] I have three sections: Title, Status, Priority, Time and Date, that are vertically aligned in that order. My problem is that when I setText() 'time' or 'date', the 'Priority' section and 'Time and Date' section get hoisted up. That is to say, the title of the 'Priority' section is completely align with the top bar and the 'Time and Date' title is right alongside it overlapping the content (instead of being below it).

The other two sections remain in their spot (at the top) but they are overlapped.

At the bottom are pictures.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Title -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TitleLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_string"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/TitleLabel"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enter_title_string" 
        android:inputType="textShortMessage">

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <!-- Status -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/title"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/status_string"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/statusGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/status"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/statusDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/done_string" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/statusNotDone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/not_done_string" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <!-- Priority -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/priority"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/statusGroup"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/priority_string"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/priorityGroup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/priority"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/priority_string" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/lowPriority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/priority_low_string" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/medPriority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="@string/priority_medium_string" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/highPriority"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/priority_high_string" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <!-- Time and Date -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_and_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/priorityGroup"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/time_and_date_string"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_and_date"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/no_date_set_string" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/time_and_date"
        android:text="@string/no_time_set_string" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/date_picker_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/date"
        android:text="@string/choose_date_string" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/time_picker_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/date_picker_button"
        android:layout_below="@id/time"
        android:text="@string/choose_time_string" />

    <!-- Buttons -->

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:text="@string/cancel_string" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/reset_string" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submitButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/submit_string" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the method I use to set it. I played around by commenting stuff and with an inclusive OR, if I set the date text or the time text, it all gets hoisted up.

Here is the full code of the activity:
See setDefaultDateTime for where the setText occurs.

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

public class AddToDoActivity extends Activity {

    // 7 days in milliseconds - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    private static final int SEVEN_DAYS = 604800000;

    private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

    private static String timeString;
    private static String dateString;
    private static TextView dateView;
    private static TextView timeView;


    private Date mDate;
    private RadioGroup mPriorityRadioGroup;
    private RadioGroup mStatusRadioGroup;
    private EditText mTitleText;
    private RadioButton mDefaultStatusButton;
    private RadioButton mDefaultPriorityButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.add_todo);

        mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
        mDefaultStatusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.statusNotDone);
        mDefaultPriorityButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.medPriority);
        mPriorityRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.priorityGroup);
        mStatusRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.statusGroup);
        dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

        // Set the default date and time

        setDefaultDateTime();

        // OnClickListener for the Date button, calls showDatePickerDialog() to show
        // the Date dialog

        final Button datePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_picker_button);
        datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showDatePickerDialog();
            }
        });

        // OnClickListener for the Time button, calls showTimePickerDialog() to show
        // the Time Dialog

        final Button timePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_picker_button);
        timePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showTimePickerDialog();
            }
        });

        // OnClickListener for the Cancel Button, 

        final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                log("Entered cancelButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                //TODO - Implement onClick().  
                setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);

                finish();
            }
        });

        //OnClickListener for the Reset Button

        final Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                log("Entered resetButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                //TODO - Reset data fields to default values
                mTitleText.setText("");
                setDefaultDateTime();
                mStatusRadioGroup.setId(R.id.statusDone);
                mPriorityRadioGroup.setId(R.id.medPriority);
            }
        });

        // OnClickListener for the Submit Button
        // Implement onClick().

        final Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                log("Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

                // Gather ToDoItem data  

                //TODO - Get Priority
                Priority priority = getPriority();

                //TODO -  Get Status
                Status status = getStatus();

                //TODO -  Title
                String titleString = mTitleText.getText().toString();

                // Date
                String fullDate = dateString + " " + timeString;

                // Package ToDoItem data into an Intent
                Intent data = new Intent();
                ToDoItem.packageIntent(data, titleString, priority, status, fullDate);

                //TODO - return data Intent and finish
                setResult(RESULT_OK, data);

                finish();
            }
        });
    }

    // Use this method to set the default date and time

    private void setDefaultDateTime() {

        // Default is current time + 7 days
        mDate = new Date();
        mDate = new Date(mDate.getTime() + SEVEN_DAYS);

        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(mDate);

        setDateString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        dateView.setText(dateString);

        setTimeString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
                c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

        timeView.setText(timeString);
    }

    private static void setDateString(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        // Increment monthOfYear for Calendar/Date -> Time Format setting
        monthOfYear++;
        String mon = "" + monthOfYear;
        String day = "" + dayOfMonth;

        if (monthOfYear < 10)
            mon = "0" + monthOfYear;
        if (dayOfMonth < 10)
            day = "0" + dayOfMonth;

        dateString = year + "-" + mon + "-" + day;
    }

    private static void setTimeString(int hourOfDay, int minute, int mili) {
        String hour = "" + hourOfDay;
        String min = "" + minute;

        if (hourOfDay < 10)
            hour = "0" + hourOfDay;
        if (minute < 10)
            min = "0" + minute;

        timeString = hour + ":" + min + ":00";
    }

    private Priority getPriority() {

        switch (mPriorityRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.lowPriority: {
            return Priority.LOW;
        }
        case R.id.highPriority: {
            return Priority.HIGH;
        }
        default: {
            return Priority.MED;
        }
        }
    }

    private Status getStatus() {

        switch (mStatusRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.statusDone: {
            return Status.DONE;
        }
        default: {
            return Status.NOTDONE;
        }
        }
    }

    // DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline date

    public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth) {
            setDateString(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

            dateView.setText(dateString);
        }

    }

    // DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline time

    public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
            int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

            // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return
            return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                    true);
        }

        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            setTimeString(hourOfDay, minute, 0);

            timeView.setText(timeString);
        }
    }

    private void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }

    private void showTimePickerDialog() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
        newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
    }

    private void log(String msg) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i(TAG, msg);
    }

}
```

Any ideas? I appreciate your help!

Pics:

[image: Before]

[image: After]

Comment: could you post print screen till we can see how it display

Comment: is the above XML layout part of a linear layout? relative layout? more context, please

Comment: Please post an image before the problem and after the problem(image).

Comment: Disregard, I found a camera, give me a second

Comment: could you post more code ??

Comment: are you using any `visibility` api. I tested your XML, with adding data, seems fine for me. you can take screenshot of your device by long pressing `volumeUp + power`

Comment: I am not using the visibility API. Maybe my phone is just stupid. Also, VU + P does not work :(

Comment: the problems in your code in this lines 
mStatusRadioGroup.setId(R.id.statusDone);
                mPriorityRadioGroup.setId(R.id.medPriority);

why you set id for the views ??

Comment: Oh! I thought I was selecting the radio button to me checked. Please write the answer so I can give you top.

Comment: Future Readers: At least on my phone, it was volumeDown and Power

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems in your code in this code

```
 mStatusRadioGroup.setId(R.id.statusDone); 
 mPriorityRadioGroup.setId(R.id.medPriority);
```